# Sudden Errors while Uploading Files with Powershell to Sharepoint

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

I'm uploading images (< 100kb) to a SharePoint Document Library using Powershell. The first 30-40 Files upload perfectly but then all of a sudden I receive this message:

```
Exception calling "UploadFile" with "3" argument(s): "An exception occurred during a WebClient request." At D:\SP01\Scripts\E_Zeitkonto\PSURLCapture\PSURLCapture.ps1:153 char:26
+     $WebClient.UploadFile <<<< ($UploadFullPath, "PUT", $LocalPath)
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException
```

The code for uploading the files is:

```
Function UploadToSPPictureLib($LocalPath, $spDocLibPath) 
{
    $UploadFullPath = $spDocLibPath + "/" + $(split-path -leaf $LocalPath) 
    $WebClient = new-object System.Net.WebClient 
    $WebClient.Credentials = [System.Net.CredentialCache]::DefaultCredentials 
    $WebClient.UploadFile($UploadFullPath, "PUT", $LocalPath)

    $WebClient.Dispose()
}
```

Whats wrong here? What am I missing?

Comment: What's the value of $UploadFullpath when the call to Uploadfile crashes? Can you use Fiddler to see what happens on the http side?

Comment: If I had to guess (without knowing exactly what the value of `$UploadFullPath`) I would say that you are using a `Get-ChildItem` to get the files and passing that to the function.

One problem that you may be having is if you use `Get-ChildItem` it will also get the directories, and when you pass the directory it will not work.